# Button Animation WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

Hello I am trying to make an `animation` on `button`, it does increase the `width` and `height` on `IsMouseOver`, However, when the `IsMouseOver` is `false`, It does not return to its Original place with an animation.

here is my **.XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Button Margin="355,0,0,0" Width="100" Height="300">
        <Image Source="img/blue.jpg" />
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="320" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="120" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="300" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="100" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should place animation to `Trigger.ExitActions` like this.

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" 
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="120" 
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="120" 
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" 
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="100" 
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="100" 
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Comment: worked like a charm, I had another question, is it possible that it only grows only for example from left-side?

Comment: It's possible if the button is placed into `Grid` container and it's properties set like `HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"`